# How to Update google drive docs uploaded using service account api in web ui?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-docs

In my JAVA application i want to use Google drive and for that i have created on "Service Account" in google drive.

I have successfully done task of upload and download docs in google drive using the "Service Account" API.

Now, I want to give the functionality of the edit document direct in web UI without downloading the doc in local machine. How it is possible? please give me solution of the this problem.

Comment: you can't. Service accounts have no users and so no user UI.

Comment: is it possible connecting Drive SDK with the Service account?

Answer (score 0):

please refer this link

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts

this link is more beneficial and helping for uploading Google drive document